# Can the share box on main not be charcoal?

Tags: feature-request, design

*Click "share" beneath any post and a box pops up:*

[image: screenshot]

*I think the charcoal gray looks out of place on our main site. I propose something like:*

[image: screenshot]

*(That's `.share-tip{background-color:#853}.share-tip a,.share-tip a:visited{color:#095}`.)*

*Thoughts?*

*As usual, please downvote this if you disagree, upvote it if you agree, and propose other solutions in answers.*

Comment: I think it helps it to stand out. It also is hard to see the 'close' function in the brown scheme.

Comment: @SethJ I picked a green for 'close', but it can remain the light blue it is, or another color. But re the background color, okay, makes sense.